# Using UrlDecode from a WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, urldecode

I am creating a test app that will work with query string values. I want to use the HttpUtility.UrlDecode.

When I try to add a refernce to the System.Web, System.Web is not availble in the list.

When I create a web project in the same solution, System.Web is automatically added.

I also tried referencing the web project from the winforms project, but that does not seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can use UrlDecode from a winforms app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This probably because you are targeting the [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx). Try changing to the full .NET Framework and you will be able to reference `System.Web`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was it (PS have to wait 9 mins to accept the answer)